# counting number of rows having not null values in hive

Tags: hive

I have a query how to count no of rows present in a table having not null value.

Suppose, below data set is having 8 column h1,h2,h3......h8. if all the all the column is having NULL then the count is 0. if at least one column is having value then the count is 1.

```
h1   h2  h3  h4  h5  h6  h7  h8

U   U   NULL    U   Y   NULL    Y   X

U   NULL    U   U   Y   Y   X   X

U   U   U   NULL    U   NULL    Y   NULL

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

X   V   U   U   Y   NULL    Z   X

Y   X   NULL        X   Y   Z   U

X   NULL    U   NULL    NULL    U   Z   Y

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

FOr above data set the answer will be 6. since only two rows(4 and 6) are such which is having all the column as NULL.

Please suggest the command in hive to get the result.

Comment: For the same above data set, how can we count the occurrence of value in the table. In short count how many times U, Y, X, Z, V have occurred in the data set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a combination of `CASE` ,`COALESCE` and `SUM`.

```
SELECT SUM (
  CASE
    WHEN COALESCE (h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8) IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END)
FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works!

I tried below logic but its throwing error. could you please suggest where i am wrong. 

select sum(case when h1 is null then 0 else (case when h2 is null then 0 else (case when h3 is null then 0 else (case when h4 is null then 0 else (case when h5 is null then 0 else (case when h6 is null then 0 else (case when h7 is null then 0 else (case when h8 is null then 0 else 1 END)))))))) as count_of from table;